# SQL Server : mirror/cache current day data for performance reasons

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, caching, mirroring

Is there any existing (non-proprietary) solution how to mirror current day data onto separate disk with minimum delay (under second), so that I can use smaller, non redundant but more expensive disk for high rate of reads? (specifically for SQL Server 2012)

More background:

- We have a transnational DB that needs to be redundant, there are few dozen thousands of new rows daily (handled without any problem); but main perf impact on DB is from reads that happen few times per second. Reads need to have fresh data (at max 1 second old), but they are only interested in current day data. All writes need to go to disk array with also very small delay.
- I can use small fast but non-redundant SSD disk to optimize reads.

There are few proprietary options - e.g. send each update to two separate nonrelated DBs - one slower and redundant; and other faster for reading.

However is there any existing solution for this - how to mirror all inserts to secondary DB (and purge each midnight)?

Comment: Are the writes really of any concern at all? A few dozen thousand rows per day are nothing. Can we take the writes out of the question? How big is the data set that is being read?

Comment: @usr Writes can be really taken out of question - but only performance-wise. The new data needs to be always immediately available to reads. Reads operates on all data from current day, but not on all columns - indexing by date and including needed columns is already in place

Comment: Whats your current high availability story? Synchronous mirroring? Clustering?

Comment: How big is the data set that is being read? Does it fit into RAM? In that case you're done.

Comment: Have you looked at a indexed view, where the index is stored on your fast io disks.

Comment: @usr Can you please elaborate more on option of data set that fits in RAM?
It would definitely fit in RAM on SQL server box, very likely also on Web server box.
So is there any out of the box solution that would refresh the data set in memory everytime the DB is being updated? Or will Ineed to take care about this myself.
Btw. there is currently no high availability solution in place; Only data redundancy facilitated by disk mirroring + backups.

Comment: @conan I like your suggestion a lot! It is actually almost a complete answer to my question. What do you think would be the easiest way to force the view to hold only the current day data? I guess that GETUTCDATE() function cannot be used in WHERE clause of materialized view (as it is nondeterministic), maybe a scheduled nightly sql task?
Feel free to post your suggestion as regular answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an indexed view to store the current days data on a separate dataspace. You'll have to build a new view each day so you may want to use a synonym to do the actual switching so as to avoid locks on insert while creating the view. Make sure you end date the filter on the column. This is how i would do it using to agent jobs:

```
Job 1 (10 Minutes to midnight)

create view my_view_yyyymmdd (yyyymmdd = today + 1)
with schema_binding 
as 
select from mytable where datecol >=day+1 and datecol < today+2 --dateliterals;
create clustered index on my_view_yyyymmdd (yyyymmdd = today + 1)


Job2 (midnight + 1 second)
drop synonym mysyn;
create synonym mysyn for my_view_yyyymmdd (yyyymmdd = today )
drop view my_view_yyyymmdd my_view_yyyymmdd (yyyymmdd = today - 1)
```

You don't mention updates so a clustered index on date shouldn't fragment enough to worry about. You may want to set the fillfactor on the index to 100 which will reduce the size on disk by 20 % over the default. This will help further reduce the IO hit.

Comment: Couldn't he just use a filtered index for this? Or does he want to materialize joins?

Comment: You could use a filtered index for this, as with the indexed view you would need to recreate it every day at midnight. Although you can do it online with drop_existing. There would be no guarentee however that the optimiser would use it for every query. It should, but it may not. One advantage of the indexed view is you could if required add additional non-clustered indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You say in the comments that the data to be queried fits in RAM on the SQL Server box. This means that SQL Server will never perform even a single physical IO to read data. It all comes from its buffer pool.

Read latencies will be extremely low. Disk performance will not matter at all. If you properly structure and index the data read queries will execute blindingly fast.

Usually, having enough RAM to fit all data into memory is the single most beneficial thing you can do to performance.

You can use any high availability solution you like. It will only impact writes, not reads. We already concluded in the comments that writes do not matter much here.

In other words, I don't think you have a problem.

Comment: I've probably misunderstood your question and so provided you misleading info... Your statements would be completely wright in case nothing else would be running on that SQL server. However there are other DBs on that server and one of them is really heavy-weight (thousands of records inserted every second). So the dataset in question would fit into memory, but SQL server is using the memory for other things (we moved DB in question to SSD disk as a quick experiment and it helped performance significantly). Moving the DB to separate server is unfortunately not possible (licensing + HW costs)

Comment: Ok can you just move the read-intensive DB onto the SSD as well? That should also solve the issue. You can try keeping the DB in memory by performing a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T` on all relevant tables every 10sec or so. That will keep them in memory.

Comment: The query is being performed each second - yet it still generates I/O traffic.
I want to have the read-intensive DB on SSD (actually just the current day data), but still have it also on slower disk to ensure that no data would be lost under no circumstances - that was actually exactly what I was trying to ask in my question

Comment: SQL Server cannot ever tolerate a whole database file to be lost safely. You're likely to be lucky if only indexes are on it, but it is never guaranteed that you can recover any data at all if you lose files. You *must* have a different strategy (e.g. restore from backup). Recommendation: put all data files onto the SSD and just there. Put the transaction log onto "safe" storage. Run in FULL recovery mode and take regular FULL and LOG backups. That allows you to restore without any data loss (not one second) in case the SSD is lost. Log-ship to a 2nd server in addition.

Comment: Btw, the IO traffic you see is probably logical. It is not physical.

Comment: +1 for warnings about recovery story - we'll need to review this as well. For now all data files are on mirrored RAID array - so unless the whole array is lost the files are still there.

Answer (score 0):

what about having two databases, one for today and another for historical data (yesterday and previously), with all the same tables. when new data is added just write it to today's database  and at midnight( or whenever is most appropriate) write todays data to historical database and truncate todays tables. You can keep todays database on SSD and historical on whatever disks you choose.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot afford this. All data need to written with redundancy (provided only by slower disk) - and the redundancy need to be guaranteed at the time when service successfully inserts the data.
Possible alternative of your suggestion is sending each update to both of those unrelated databases (as is already mentioned in my question) - I'm trying to see if there is any other option (more transparent for inserting service).